# Perl simple loop

Tags: perl, loops, for-loop

Can somebody explain why my loop does not work?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
use URI;
use Web::Scraper;

my $url = "http://example.com";


# prepare data
my $scrapedata = scraper {
 process "div.something", 'pages[]' => '@rel';
};

# scrape the data
my $res = $scrapedata->scrape(URI->new($url));

# Get number of pages and define as var
for my $j (0 .. $#{$res->{pages}}) {
 my $varpages = $res->{pages}[$j];
  print "$varpages\n";
}


for ( my $count = 2; $count <= $varpages; $count++) {

print "$varpages\n";
print "$count\n";

}
```

This is the error :

```
# perl oli
Global symbol "$varpages" requires explicit package name at oli line 25.
Global symbol "$varpages" requires explicit package name at oli line 27.
Execution of oli aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: What value do you expect $varpages to have after leaving the first loop?

Comment: I want the value scraped from:
process "div.something", 'pages[]' => '@rel';

Answer (score 6):

`$varpages` is lexically scoped to the code block:

```
# Get number of pages and define as var
for my $j (0 .. $#{$res->{pages}}) {
 my $varpages = $res->{pages}[$j];
  print "$varpages\n";
}
```

The attempt to reference it later references a different variable.  If you want `$varpages` to have global scope, declare it outside the block that assigns to it.  For example:

```
my $varpages;
# Get number of pages and define as var
for my $j (0 .. $#{$res->{pages}}) {
  $varpages = $res->{pages}[$j];
  print "$varpages\n";
}
```

Comment: Hello,
So I defined the $varpages var before the loop, and now I have the following error:
Use of uninitialized value $varpages in numeric le (<=) at 6

Comment: That would certainly happen if `$#{$res->{pages}` is zero.  Try initializing: `my $varpages = 0;`

Comment: Did you remove the 'my' from 'my $varpages' inside the for-loop, as William suggested?

Comment: Ups, I didn't. That was the problem. Thanks for this and for William also for pointing the problem.